# Extra changeColumns in Doctrine generate-migrations-diff

Tags: php, symfony1, migration, doctrine

I'm generating migrations between different yaml schema files: i.e. running:

symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff

And the resulting migration file has a whole slew of changeColumn calls that weren't added in the last schema file change.

For example, if you run generate-migrations-diff without changing your schema file whatsoever, you should get an empty up() function.  However, the function that results for me has a changeColumn call for virtually every table in my database.

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: is your db synched with the former yml ? the task compares the current db and the new yml. afaik you cannot compare two yml directly with the default command line task (first you have to sync your actual db with the first one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The generate-migrations-diff doesn't diff two different yaml files. It actually compares your models and your yaml file and then generates a migration based on the differences. If you start from a db that is in sync with your yaml and classes, your workflow to make schema changes should be:

1. Change yaml file
2. **generate-migrations-diff** to diff your current (changed) yaml with your (unchanged) models. This will generate a migrations file in your doctrine/migrations directory (or whatever migrations_path is set to in your doctrine config).
3. **migrate** to run the migration created in step 2 and modify your database
4. **generate-models-yaml** to generate new classes based on your yaml file. These go where you've specified your generated models go (models_path in your doctrine config).
5. **generate-sql** to generate a SQL file. This will go where your doctrine sql_path config is set to.