# Correct way to do a migrations diff

Tags: orm, migration, doctrine, diff

I'm trying to perform a migrations diff between the schema yaml file and my database, using the following code

```
    $migration = new Doctrine_Migration($migrationsPath);
    $diff = new Doctrine_Migration_Diff(null, $yamlSchemaPath, $migration);
    $changes = $diff->generateMigrationClasses();

    $numChanges = count($changes, true) - count($changes);
```

From what I gather, $from = null here would imply that the from in comparison will be read from the database, but that does not seem to be the case.

Reading about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855925/extra-changecolumns-in-doctrine-generate-migrations-diff) i've performed the following steps to make sure the basic routine is not at fault.

1. Change yaml file
2. **generate-migrations-diff** to diff
   your current (changed) yaml with
   your (unchanged) models. This will
   generate a migrations file in your
   doctrine/migrations directory (or
   whatever migrations_path is set to
   in your doctrine config).
3. **migrate** to run the migration created
   in step 2 and modify your database
4. **generate-models-yaml** to generate new
   classes based on your yaml file.
   These go where you've specified your
   generated models go (models_path in
   your doctrine config).
5. **generate-sql** to generate a SQL file.
   This will go where your doctrine
   sql_path config is set to.

The $numChanges is always the same when the schema yaml file isn't changed. It does not compare against the current database that is in sync and working.

Can someone spot an error or perhaps tell me the correct way of doing it?